# ¿Que es mejor muchas funciones cada una con su consulta llamando registro por registro o una sola consulta con un solo array?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Hola a todos por primera vez vengo aqui no porque mi codigo no funcione jaja sino porque pienso que cuando tenga muchos registros mi base de datos se alentara, les explico estoy generando un documento pdf y tiene valores que tomo de la base de datos por no complicarme la vida he tomado un codigo que encontre por ahi:

```
class Tabla {
        public function folio() {
                try {
                $orden_de_compra = $_GET['orden_de_compra'];
                include("resource/Database.php");

                $q= $db->query("SELECT folio FROM salida_materiales WHERE orden_de_compra=$orden_de_compra");
    $folio = $q->fetchColumn();




            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                //echo "Exeption: " .$e->getMessage();
                $result = false;
            }
            $query = null;
            $db = null;
            return $folio;        
        }

}
```

Estos valores no van en una tabla sino que en la pagina van separados así que tengo que llamarlo entre lineas de texto y hago lo siguiente para cada uno que ya son un montón he pensado en empezar a usar un array.¿Es una mala practica? no quiero que mi proyecto puesto en marcha de problemas a la larga por cierto la consulta a mariadb no se cierra? que nunca lo he hecho.

```
$tabla = new Tabla();


  $cliente = $tabla->cliente();

$html2 = utf8_decode('<br>Destino: <b>'. ($cliente) . '</b>');
```

Comment: Las consultas en MariaDB, MySql cuando tienen gran volumen de Datos se hacen muy lentas, por lo que siempre sugiero optimizar la cantidad de consultas a Base de Datos, si puedes obtener los datos en menos consultas, seria lo mejor.
Respecto a PHP la única vez que tuve problemas por un gran volumen de datos fue por el nro de columnas que tenia la consulta (120 aprox) mas no por la filas (aprox 100000), la solución fue hacer consultas en grupos de 40000 registros, se creo un for donde almacenaba los datos en un array, procesaba, luego limpiaba el array antes de recibir los 40000 registros sgtes

Comment: @juliocpiro Gracias por la informacion pensaba en hacer algo asi utilizar mi funcion colocar select valor, valor2 etc from , hacer la consulta  y regresar un array en la funcion despues cada vez que ocupe un dato ir tomandolo del array ya obtenido

Comment: La pregunta no queda clara... ¿Cuál es la consulta que llamas registro por registro y desde qué contexto la llamas? Generalmente no hay problema de lentitud, si las tablas están bien indexadas, es un aspecto importante que debes controlar. Para que lo guardes en la recámara y pienses en resolverlo cuando tengas respuesta a esta pregunta: **tu código es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL**.

Comment: @A.Cedano la funcion que tengo arriba es una de muchas iguales cada una haciendo un select a un solo campo y haciendo un return que devuleve un solo campo de la base de datos, en otros codigos hago esto para evitar la inyeccion $insertStmt = $db->prepare( y con values asi que usan :cliente pero como es un pdf y ocuparas logearte no le tome importancia, pero si es vulnerable debo corregir eso

Comment: @A.Cedano Yo siempre he visto la inyeccion sql peligrosa si existen campos de texto se puede realizar inyeccion aun si no existen campos en el mismo archivo php? es decir si tengo inputs pero eso lo hago en otro archivo y ahi si uso parametros, me imagino seria modficando el html tema del que no conozco

Comment: Supongamos que en esta consulta: `SELECT folio FROM salida_materiales WHERE orden_de_compra=$orden_de_compra`  la variable `$orden_de_compra` es tomada de un formulario u otra fuente externa. Cuando pasas esa variable tal cual a la base de datos, tendrías inyección tan sólo con que alguien escriba esto en el  input que recoge el valor de la variable: `1; DROP TABLE salida_materiales; DROP TABLE otra-tabla;  UPDATE administradores SET password='hacked' WHERE usuario='admin';` de ese modo te borran tablas o toman el control de tu bd o hasta del sistema. No pruebes las consultas, son peligrosas.

Comment: @A.Cedano la obtengo con get del link de la url o como se llame, asi que supngo que la barra de direcciones serviria como input para la inyeccion sql entonces si utilizo parametros y prepare el pasar variables por medio de la url es seguro?

Comment: La barra de direcciones es _pefecta_ para que te inyecten código. Si recoges un `$_POST["orden_de_compra"]` y alguien escribe esto: `tu-dominio.com/rest.php?orden_de_compra=1; DROP TABLE salida_materiales; DROP TABLE otra-tabla; UPDATE administradores SET password='hacked' WHERE usuario='admin';` o, si es en forma de API: `tu-dominio.com/rest/orden_de_compra/1; DROP TABLE salida_materiales; DROP TABLE otra-tabla; UPDATE administradores SET password='hacked' WHERE usuario='admin';` **¡tendrás terribles inyecciones!**